# SSRS hidden column creates extra blank page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with a Tablix where I would like it almost full page width. "Gross Pay" is visible or not based on a parameter. I have also added a blank column to the left of this which has the opposite visibility to "Gross Pay" as a work around for the fact that I can't resize tablix width dynamically so the whole tablix stays the same width.

This is all fine and works but spits out an extra page when saving to pdf. This is because my body width is greater than 21cm. Below is the tablix, the red line is where page end is.

[image]

My body width must be 24cm in the designer to accommodate this hidden field but will always display under 21cm in the end. Can I have a body width in the designer larger than the page size? Alternate solutions would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the blank column and just using expressions for all fields on the "Gross Pay" column that would fill it as blank if appropriate parameter was set.